# Run program without permission

Tags: debian, terminal, htop

I'm using Debian 10, and today I suddenly realize my CPU up to 100 percent and I use htop to saw which process take action, and I saw my system try to unrar a file in my download directory but I don't ask for it, can some say me what happened to my system?

Comment: There is a known ransomware attack using RAR, but it works by *creating* an encrypted .rar. Are you sure yours was unpacking? Search `All_Your_Documents.rar`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a desktop, as on server you probably wouldn't have download directory. If this is a server, then this is much more alarming.

It might be a sign that something is very wrong, but on desktop, unraring a directory might happen without you doing it 100% explicitly. Is it possible that you have just downloaded this RAR and asked browser to open it? Is it possible you (maybe through a keyboard shortcut or misclick) asked your filebrowser to show its content?

Possible approaches to investigation

- Should something similar happen again, check `htop` and view it in a tree (shortcut `F5`) to see who/what launched the unrar.
- You can also check who launched a process here: https://serverfault.com/questions/232762/linux-how-to-know-where-a-process-was-started-and-how-it-was-started/232774
- You can create AppArmor profile that will limit rar/unrar and than see in audit logs when it was launched

Comment: Thank you for answering, it happens on my desktop, and the file was download yesterday. But that doesn't happen again. I will check those parameters if it happens one more time.